# How do i resolve this?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am getting this notice on wordpress

> constant PHP_INT_MIN - assumed 'PHP_INT_MIN' in /home/myusername/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wpsso/lib/com/util.php on line 488.

How do I resolve this?

```
add_filter( $filter_name, array( __CLASS__, 'filter_value_save' ), PHP_INT_MIN, 1 );
        add_filter( $filter_name, array( __CLASS__, 'filter_value_restore' ), PHP_INT_MAX, 1 );

        return true;
    }

    public static function remove_filter_protection( $filter_name ) {
        if ( ! has_filter( $filter_name, array( __CLASS__, 'filter_value_restore' ) ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        remove_filter( $filter_name, array( __CLASS__, 'filter_value_save' ), PHP_INT_MIN );
        remove_filter( $filter_name, array( __CLASS__, 'filter_value_restore' ), PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Comment: Well. showing us some code would be a start.

Comment: A quick google shows this constant should be defined in `wp-includes/ID3/getid3.lib.php` - which is a core WP file, and has been since version 3.6 of Wordpress. What version are you using?

Comment: Write this to top of index php define("PHP_INT_MIN",0);

Comment: @thebluefox i am using version 4.7.4

Comment: add_filter( $filter_name, array( __CLASS__, 'filter_value_save' ), PHP_INT_MIN, 1 );
   add_filter( $filter_name, array( __CLASS__, 'filter_value_restore' ), PHP_INT_MAX, 1 );

   return true;
  }

  public static function remove_filter_protection( $filter_name ) {
   if ( ! has_filter( $filter_name, array( __CLASS__, 'filter_value_restore' ) ) ) {
    return false;
   }
   remove_filter( $filter_name, array( __CLASS__, 'filter_value_save' ), PHP_INT_MIN );
   remove_filter( $filter_name, array( __CLASS__, 'filter_value_restore' ), PHP_INT_MAX ); @thebluefox

Comment: @kodmanyagha suggestion would solve the problem, but I'd say it was a poor solution. You need to investigate why that constant isn't being set. It looks like it's only set if you're running Wordpress on a 32-bit system, If you're running on a 64-bit system, it doesn't set the constant as it should be defined as of PHP 5.0.5. What PHP version are you using? Also - please add the code as an edit to your original post.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Wordpress itself, or to anything in a [tag:plugin]? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PHP_INT_MIN` is a predefined constant in PHP that has been available since PHP7.

`PHP_INT_MAX` on the other hand has existed since an early version of PHP5.

You're running the site on a server that's using an older version of PHP (pre-7) and therefore don't have access to the `PHP_INT_MIN` constant. The notice is telling you that the constant doesn't exist so it's being converted into a string instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

As this issue is occurring in a third-party plugin, you shouldn't be modifying the code yourself. You have a few options including contacting your host about updating your PHP version; notifying the plugin author of the issue and hoping they release a fix; or manually defining the constant yourself in an appropriate location.