# From which php version the constant PHP_INT_MAX exists?

Tags: php, constants

Is this documented somewhere from which version any specific PHP constant is defined?

Specifically, I would like to know about the following two:
`PHP_INT_MAX`
`PHP_INT_MIN`

Someone has mentioned here - [How do i resolve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734024/how-do-i-resolve-this)

But I don't see in the PHP official documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: You can test this out [online](https://3v4l.org/T0pZA)

Comment: The link you gave already says in which versions they were defined. As DarkBee says you can also prove it by demonstration. If its not documented officially and you think it should be, submit an issue to the php team.

Comment: Understood thanks.

Comment: Why do you care? Are you facing any specific problem with these constants?

Comment: I have a plugin on WordPress, so I support a range of PHP versions. To keep the compatibility intact I need to understand/know it before using it.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 3):

That constant exists since Version 5.1.0

> Added PHP_INT_MAX and PHP_INT_SIZE as predefined constants. (Andrey)

As stated in the [changelog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php).

Comment: See the full changelog. It was seemingly backported to some older versions: https://3v4l.org/T0pZA

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Did you see it the documentation earlier? I could not find it.

Comment: It's in your own link for PHP/5 (search for "Added PHP_INT_MAX and PHP_INT_SIZE as predefined constants." in the page). The [PHP/4 change log](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-4.php), though, does not mention it at all.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, that's what I meant. That it is not mentioned earlier is somewhat curious. Maybe it was not taken that serious.